# How to convert a PDF into an array of PNG and download them as .zip file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I tryed a lot of different npm packages, I believed that https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/convert-pdf-png could be the solution but I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:27)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1257:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:14)
> at ModuleWrap. (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:155:15)
> at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:140:23)
> at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:162:24)
> at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)

Do you have other solutions?

Comment: I you've copy-pasted the code inside a not 'module' app, it's normal... Try to use `const convertPdfToPng = require('convert-pdf-png').convertPdfToPng` maybe... Or something else...

Comment: @BENARDPatrick I tried but it is not working. Same error